# Is there a matplotlib method that allows to plot a vector field on a surface so that the surface is opaque to the vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mplot3d

I wrote a matplotlib program that plots a 2d surface embedded in three dimensional space using plot_trisurf() and then plots a vector field defined on the surface using quiver(). I'd like the surface to be opaque to the vector field but instead the program plots both the vectors that are in front of the surface and those that are behind the surface with respect to the camera, despite the surface's alpha value being 1.0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
```

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1.0) * 1.7)

# Make a mesh in the space of parameterisation variables u and v
u = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, endpoint=True, num=30)    # u: theta
v = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, endpoint=True, num=60)    # v: phi
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)

u, v = u.flatten(), v.flatten()

x, y, z = F(u, v)

# Triangulate parameter space to determine the triangles
tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)

# Plot the surface.  The triangles in parameter space determine which x, y, z
# points are connected by an edge.
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.magma, alpha = 1.0)
xl = ax.get_xlim()
yl = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_zlim(xl[0], xl[1])
plt.show()
```

Here's where the vector field gets plotted:

```
alpha = 1.0
lenght = 0.25
ax.quiver(xf, yf, zf, ox, oy, oz, color='red', alpha=alpha, length=lenght, normalize=True)
```

Here's an example that shows how the full vector field gets plotted.

[image: example]

I've also tried adding [zorder](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) parameters in the plotting functions but with no success: `ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.magma, alpha = 1.0, zorder = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Set `antialiased=False` in `plot_trisurf`

[image]

Comment: Hi. It didn't work.

Comment: By Matplotlib 3.6 or 3.5: `ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.magma, alpha=1.0, antialiased=False)` By Matplotlib 3.4: Use `antialiaseds=False`

Comment: I'm currently running Matplotlib version 3.2.2

Comment: Tip: Use virtual environments in your Python projects. So you can use different versions of packages and libraries. Search about it.

Comment: I upgraded matplotlib to version 3.6.1. The surface is still transparent to the vectors. Thanks anyway.